# Flex : How to center pop-up from FileReference browse?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want to screen center the file chooser which appears when the `FileReference.browse()` method is called.

Answer (score 1):

`FileReference.browse()` calls your system's file dialog and waits for the answer. This window is not managed by flash, this is an OS window, you can't do anything with it except what is allowed by the API: add file types in the filters list.

Answer (score 1):

The Popup that you see when you call FileReference.browse() it is a modal browser window.
This is not controlled or derived from flash, so basically you have no control on it.
The position is controlled 100% by the browser.